# Spring Boot - How does @ModelAttribute know where to map values?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Given the example code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
    // Code that uses the employee object

    return "employeeView";
}
```

and

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/spring-mvc-basics/addEmployee" 
  modelAttribute="employee">
    <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="name" />
    
    <form:label path="id">Id</form:label>
    <form:input path="id" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

and

```
public class Employee {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // standard getters and setters removed
}
```

How does Spring know which fields to map to which class variables? I've played around with it quite a bit and it seems that no matter what the GTML fields are named, and no matter what the class `Employee` names its class variables, it always magically puts the data in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors know.

[Handler Mappings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) know how to map the request to corresponding handler method, and [Handler Interceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) know how to intercept the call chain (`dispatcher -> interceptor(s) here.. -> handler`) and do all the pre-processing job, in order to prepare all the arguments for the handler method, and call it eventually.

Comment: I'm really asking how the @RequestMapping knows how to bind the correct data to the `Employee` object.

Comment: 1. Your comment contradicts with the question's title; 2. @RequestMapping doesn't bind anything, its sole role is to *map* the handler method to the particular URL(s). You can still make use of this answer.